# Codeigniter MSSQL/SQLSRV Connection

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I'm working on a web app that connects to a MSSQL database. I previously managed to connect to the database without any problems, however I made a minor change to the sqlsrv_driver file. I encountered the below error, rolled my changes back to the original file, but there are still issues.

I have ensured that I have relevant MS drivers installed, correct port number used, etc however its returning this error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: D:...\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 124
```

Further to this I have made a connection out side of codeigniter via the sqlsrv_connect function. Which a successful connection is made with no errors.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

For connection from PHP->SQLSrv you need install these drivers :

a.  [Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) (SQLSRV30.EXE)

b.  [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (32bits/64bits)](http://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=5555)

c.  [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) (sqlncli.msi)

And add this row in php.ini file:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

The Driver sqlsrv is buggy. Open `/system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php`

To allow `pconnect` in your configuration, change line `89` from

```
$this->db_connect(TRUE);
```

to

```
return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
```

If you want to use `affected_rows` correctly, then change line `274` from

```
return @sqlrv_rows_affected($this->conn_id);
```

to

```
return @sqlsrv_num_rows($this->result_id);
```

I saw multiple suggestions of how to fix `affected_rows` posted elsewhere, but changing `_execute` to not use `Scrollable` will break stored sessions if you're also using sqlsrv for session validation.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem solved. And I was connecting to MSSQL hosted with microsoft Azure

Steps I followed after several research work on internet are as follows :

database.cfg :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'XXXXXXX.database.windows.net';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Mainly dbdriver,pcconnect and the hostname you should configure properly. Rest are common. Get hostname from your azure database details.

And I also modified couple of system files as I heard there were issues with DB driver.

system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php

```
function db_pconnect()
    {
        //$this->db_connect(TRUE);
        return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
    }
```

and

```
function affected_rows()
{
    //return @sqlrv_rows_affected($this->conn_id);
    return @sqlsrv_num_rows($this->result_id);
}
```

I was able to connect to database and create database application.

Hope it will help someone in need :)