# PHP 7.2.4 Apache2.4 call to undefined function srv_connect()

Tags: sql-server, apache, codeigniter-3, php-7.2

- Hope all of you guys are fine. i have installed PHP 7.2.4 and Apache
  2.4 ON Windows Server 2008 my questions is:

Applications in WWW folder is running but When i built connection with sqlsrv  it gives me below error,

### **call to undefined function srv_connect()**

***Note: I am using CodeIgniter framework.***

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the right modules in php/CI? Not 100% sure what you'll need, but I imagine you're missing either a CI module, or a php module.

A quick search gives this at the top: [Codeigniter MSSQL/SQLSRV Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398029/codeigniter-mssql-sqlsrv-connection)