# Why can't get query from sqlsrv ci3

Tags: php, sql-server, web, codeigniter-3, sqlsrv

//this my config db:

```
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '10.***.***.*',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'mydb',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => FALSE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => FALSE
```

//my model

```
class Mod_login extends CI_Model{
function Aplikasi(){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM aplikasi";
    $data = $this->db->query($sql);
    var_dump($data);
    die();
    if (!$data) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $data;
    };
}
```

}

//and this is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if ($logged_in == TRUE) {
        redirect('dashboard');
    } else {
        $aplikasi['aplikasi'] = $this->Mod_login->Aplikasi();
        $this->load->view('admin/login_data', $aplikasi);
    }
}
```

hi, im newbie and have troble with my connection to sqlsrv, i already download extension for php 8.02, make it sure my username and pass cant access the table, but still cant get the result, its really depresing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have "Message: Call to a member function result_array() on bool" you probably didn't load the database class

Read this [Initializing the Database Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/examples.html)

or see what he shows var_dump($this->db)

Comment: i just put my  "var $table = 'aplikasi';"  and  $this->load->database(); to my model, then try to "var_dump($this->db)" i thing i get the result but it get protect "object(CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver)#15 (76) { ["dbdriver"]=> string(6) "sqlsrv" ["scrollable"]=> string(8) "buffered" ["_random_keyword":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "NEWID()" [1]=> string(8) "RAND(%d)" } ["_quoted_identifier":protected]=> bool(true) ["return_delete_sql":protected]=> bool(false) ["reset_delete_data":protected]=> bool(false) ["qb_select":protected]=> array(0) { }"

Comment: and what now you see when $sql = "SELECT * FROM aplikasi";
  $data = $this->db->query($sql);
  var_dump($data->result());

Comment: is that mean i already connect to sqlsrv ?

Comment: no - if you get data from database

Comment: i still get error message "Message: Call to a member function result() on bool"

Comment: and why you "put $this->load->database(); to my model, to model" ????

Comment: open application->config->autoload.php  find $autoload['libraries'] and write $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Comment: and 'db_debug' => FALSE, change to TRUE

Comment: and for test IN controller create public function test_sql() { $sql = "SELECT * FROM aplikasi";
    $data = $this->db->query($sql);
    var_dump($data->result()); }  run this and write what you see

Comment: when i change db_debug to true its show "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings." for autoload, i already write it like this "$autoload['libraries'] = array('Template','database','form_validation','session','pagination','upload');
"

Comment: ok it happens :)

Comment: the message still same "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings."

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398029/codeigniter-mssql-sqlsrv-connection

Comment: in the end i downgrade my php version from 8.0 to 7.2 to match my sql server, thanks for the answer, its really help me to knowing my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Mod_login extends CI_Model{ function Aplikasi(){

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM aplikasi";
  $data = $this->db->query($sql);
  var_dump($data>result_array());
  die();
  if (!$data) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return $data;
  };
}
```

Comment: ->result_array();

Comment: i try it var_dump($data->result_array());
but the result "Message: Call to a member function result_array() on bool"

Comment: $this->db->select('"SELECT * FROM aplikasi');
$r = $this->db->get()->result();

Comment: try this with get()

Comment: i try it like this "       
 $this->db->select('"SELECT * FROM aplikasi');
        $r = $this->db->get()->result();
        var_dump($r);
        die();
"
the result still same "Message: Call to a member function result() on bool"