# Connection with remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, error-handling

I am connecting a remote SQL server with Codeigniter and facing an error

> ```
> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: RuntimeException
> Message: Unable to connect to the database.
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\gen-script-api\system\database\DB_driver.php
> Line Number: 434
> ```

Here are my configurations.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '......ng.com';
$db['default']['username'] = '...rod';
$db['default']['password'] = '.....r';
$db['default']['database'] = '.....v';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['port']     = "1433"; 
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = false;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I successfully connected with the local SQL server with these creds. So I doubled check the creds. But it is throwing an error in Codeigniter. Please let me know how to check errors and how to configure properly sqlsrv.

Comment: is the driver installed? see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20401461/2275490

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect with the local SQL server. But remote SQL is not establishing a connection